# How to provide google credentials json file to local apache beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, credentials

I am creating a POC on my local machine. The POC will use apache beam to read Json Pub/Sub messages from a subscription and for that subscription, I have a service account and credentials json for it. 
The question is how to provide the credentials through the json file?

There seems to be no method, `PipelineOptions` interface  like

```
setOption("credentials", new Credentials()) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a combination of:

1. PipelineOption option = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class).setProject("your GCP project");
2. setup command line env variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" to point to your credential file.

Answer (score 0):

From command line you can set Credential for project.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FULL PATH/credentials.json
```